# What is the best way to find the intervals between the array of start and end time

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having array of startTime and endTime. I want to find the actual start time and the end time from the array of intervals. The array is given below.

```js
var shiftArray = [{"startTime":"14:00:00","endTime":"21:59:59"},
                  {"startTime":"06:00:00","endTime":"13:59:59"},
                  {"startTime":"22:00:00","endTime":"05:59:59"}];
```

Expected Result is:

```js
todayShift = {"startTime":"06:00:00", "endTime":"05:59:59"};
```

Can anyone suggest some best option to achieve the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any other way than looping and comparing them

```js
var shiftArray = [{
  "startTime": "14:00:00",
  "endTime": "21:59:59"
}, {
  "startTime": "06:00:00",
  "endTime": "13:59:59"
}, {
  "startTime": "22:00:00",
  "endTime": "05:59:59"
}];
var todayShift = {
  "startTime": "23:59:59",
  "endTime": "00:00:00"
};
shiftArray.forEach(function(shift) {
  if (shift.startTime < todayShift.startTime) {
    todayShift.startTime = shift.startTime;
  }
  if (shift.endTime > todayShift.endTime) {
    todayShift.endTime = shift.endTime;
  }
})
result.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(todayShift, null, 2)
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: I suppose to get the endTime as "05:59:59" because, that is the last end time of the shift. i.e., need to find the last shift for today and get the endTime from that.